# Route to two methods of controller with one row in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, methods, laravel-4, controller, routes

It is simple to route this way:

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'PaymentsController@profile');
Route::get('user/delete', 'PaymentsController@delete');
```

I want to do this with one row:

```
Route::get('user/{subsection}', 'PaymentsController@'.$subsection);
```

but my syntax seems to be wrong. Is it possible to be done with one row? It would be nice if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that, but you can make proxy method

```
Route::get('user/{subsection}', 'PaymentsController@profileDelete');
```

And method will looks like

```
public function profileDelete($subsection) {
    return $this->$subsection();
}

public function profile(){}
public function delete(){}
```

Also, you can bind {subsection}

```
Route::bind('subsection', function ($subsection) {
   if (!in_array($subsection, ['profile', 'delete'])) {
      throw new Exception;
   }

   return $subsection;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly one row, but you can do this:

```
Route::get('user/{subsection}', function($subsection){
    if(!method_exists('PaymentsController', $subsection)){
        App::abort(404);
    }
    return App::make('PaymentsController')->callAction($subsection);
});
```

Alternatively to the `method_exists` you could also use a route condition to only allow a predefined set of subsections:

```
Route::get('user/{subsection}', function($subsection){
    return App::make('PaymentsController')->callAction($subsection);
})->where('subsection', '(profile|delete)');
```